# CakePHP find not inserting correct quotes into query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, find

I am using this code to make a list of truck types counted and sorted by type.

```
$count['type'] = $this->Type->find('all',
        array('joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'truck_has_types',
                'alias' => 'TruckHasTypes',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Type.id' => 'TruckHasTypes.types_id',
                )
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Type.id',
            'Type.name',
            'COUNT(TruckHasTypes.types_id) as N'),
            'group' => 'TruckHasTypes.types_id'
        )
    );
```

The query only returns a single result even thought there should be many more.  I found the culprit.  The query looks like this (got this from sql_dump)

```
SELECT `Type`.`id`, `Type`.`name`, COUNT(`TruckHasTypes`.`types_id`) as N FROM `douglass_cake`.`types` AS `Type` LEFT JOIN `douglass_cake`.`truck_has_types` AS `TruckHasTypes` ON (`Type`.`id` = 'TruckHasTypes.types_id') WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `TruckHasTypes`.`types_id`
```

You can see that

```
ON (`Type`.`id` = 'TruckHasTypes.types_id')
```

Does no have the same quotes as

```
ON (`Type`.`id` = `TruckHasTypes`.`types_id`)
```

I have added those quotes manually in phpmyadmin and the query is successful, but I cannot not get cakephp to automatically generate this query.  Any ideas?

Thank you!
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
$count['type'] = $this->Type->find('all',
    array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'truck_has_types',
                'alias' => 'TruckHasTypes',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Type.id=TruckHasTypes.types_id',
                )
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Type.id',
            'Type.name',
            'COUNT(TruckHasTypes.types_id) as N'
        ),
        'group' => 'TruckHasTypes.types_id'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `joins` do it "Cake way" — write model association: [Associations: Linking Models Together](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Also does `'group' => 'TruckHasTypes.types_id'` needs to be one level upper?

Comment: I have model associations for the way things need to be on the site.  This is a rare call.

Comment: 'group' is on the right level. The formatting is bad.